# How do I apply tokenizer.fit_on_texts() to a data frame with two columns of objects/strings I need to train?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I need to pass two sets of data into `tokenizer.fit_on_texts()`, but having issues with it not recognizing the text. `tokenizer.word_index()` is returning is the number 2. I suspect the issue is occurring at `tokenizer.fit_on_texts()` as I am passing it a data frame with (33481, 2) of strings. Most of the examples I have looked at have used the IMBD data set.

Additional information:
I'm currently experimenting with multi classification problem where there are headline-article pairs with labels (agree, disagree, discuss, unrelated). I plan to use LSTM and the pre-trained Glove to create an index of words mapped to known embedding.

---

### **Data**:

> `f_data` -

- Dataframe (33481, 2)
- Columns = ['Headline','articleBody'].
- Created from two other df [`x_train`(26784, 2),`val_train`(6697, 2)]
- `f_data[0]` returns

  ['did kim yo jong take kim jong un role north ko...' ,
  'san francisco marketwatch north korean leader...']

Here is a snippet of the creation `f_data`:

```
# This df will be fed into the fit_on_texts()
# Creating df to contain the train and validation set
f_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Headline', 'articleBody'])
# Adding data from x_train to f_data
f_data['Headline'] = x_train['Headline']
f_data['articleBody'] = x_train['articleBody']
# Appending x_val headline and article body columns
f_data = f_data.append(x_val[['Headline', 'articleBody']])
f_data
```

---

### **Keras/TF code Issue**

Issue:
I am having issues is that when I print out the length of word_index it returns 2:

```
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(f_data[['Headline', 'articleBody']]
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(f_data[['Headline', 'articleBody']])
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Vocab size:', len(word_index))
>> Vocab size: 2

data = pad_sequences(sequences, padding = 'post', maxlen = MAX_SEQ_LEN)
print('Shape of data tensor:', data.shape)
print('Shape of label tensor:', y_train_cat.shape)
```

I have tried turning `f_data` into ndarray but get an attribute error.

```
f_data_2 = np.array(f_data[['Headline', 'articleBody']]) # ndarray
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(apple)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Any suggestions? I have looked at some other questions, but they are dealing with a list of strings

---

**<s>Solution</s>:**
I think I finally got something to works, but I'm not entirely sure this is correct.

```
f_data = np.c_[(np.array(f_data['Headline']), np.array(f_data['articleBody']))]
f_data= f_data.tolist()
```

....

```
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(f_data)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Vocab size:', len(word_index))
print(word_index)
>> Vocab size: 3239
>> {...'judicial watch reported isis members crossed mexican border': 12,
   'isis beheads photojournalist james wright foley nasage us end intervention iraq': 13, ...} 
 #(there's 3239 strings)
```

---

**Update1:**

Above is not solution. It seems that my tokenized sentences are only recording two value and the rest are 0:

```
>Tokenized sentences: 
 [1174  102    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
    ....
    0    0    0    0]
 >shape (200,)
```

---

edit1:

```
f_head = np.array(f_data['Headline'].tolist())
f_body = np.array(f_data['articleBody'].tolist())            

#Head Tok, Seq., Pad
toke_head = Tokenizer(num_words=Max_Num_Wrd_Head)
toke_head.fit_on_texts(f_head)

seq_head = toke_head.texts_to_sequences(f_head)
wrd_indx_head = toke_head.word_index

data_Head = pad_sequences(seq_head, padding= 'post', maxlen = Max_Seq_Len_Head)

#Body Tok, Seq., Pad
toke_body = Tokenizer(num_words=MAX_NUM_WRDS_BODY)
toke_body.fit_on_texts(f_body)

seq_body = toke_body.texts_to_sequences(f_body)
wrd_indx_body = toke_body.word_index

data_Body = pad_sequences(seq_body, padding= 'post', maxlen = Max_Num_Wrd_Body)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could tokenize the two columns seperately and input them with two different input layers concatenate them and input them into the LSTM layer, right? If this approach works for you, I could explain how to do that.

Edit:
If you are comfortable using Functional API, generate the 2 padded sequence inputs corresponding to the 2 columns as follows:

```
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(f_data['Headline'])
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

headline_sequences_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(f_data['Headline'])
#headline_seq_validation = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(val_data['Headline'])

headline_padded_train = pad_sequences(headline_sequences_train, padding='post', maxlen = MAX_SEQ_LEN)
#headline_padded_validation = pad_sequences(headline_seq_validation,padding = 'post',maxlen = MAX_SEQ_LEN)
```

Similarly for article body:

```
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(f_data['articleBody'])
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

art_body_seq_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(f_data['articleBody'])
#art_body_seq_validation = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(val_data['articleBody'])

art_body_padded_train = pad_sequences(art_body_seq_train, padding='post', maxlen = MAX_SEQ_LEN)
#art_body_padded_validation = pad_sequences(art_body_seq_validation, padding='post', maxlen = MAX_SEQ_LEN)
```

Note: MAX_SEQ_LEN may be different for the two different columns. Depends on your preference. I'd suggest you to analyse the word lengths of Headline and Article Body columns seperately and select different max sequence lengths which seem suitable.

`headline_padded_train` and `art_body_padded_train` are your two inputs corresponding to the two input layers in your neural network.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't see why I could not try that. How would I got about it? Is it similar to this: https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#models-with-multiple-inputs-and-outputs ? I would say that the problem I'm working on requires one output per headline - article pair.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to use a Functional API instead of a Sequential API (which I assume you were initially planning to.) You've got the tokenization conceptually right. All you've got to do is generate 2 different padded sequences for the 2 columns. Two input layers corresponding to the 2 padded sequences followed by a concatenate layer. The output of the concatenate layer would be an input to the layer you had initially planned to be. Add all the other layers and the single output layer using the Functional API model.

Comment: The only other thing you need to keep in mind is in the model.fit() part. You would have to input the 'x' argument in model.fit() as x = [padded_seq_1,padded_seq_2]

Comment: Would I run: tokenizer.fit_on_texts(f_data[['Headline'] twice? Once for the headline and once for the articleBody? I'm going to post some code as edit1 in my question above

Comment: Check out my original answer. I have edited it. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Ah! Just finished my edit. So, in your sample you have the validation comment. Would that be added in the model.fit() like? 
model.fit(
    {"headline": f_head, ..,},
    {"articleBody": f_body,... },
    epochs=2,
    batch_size=32,
   validation_data=[art_body_seq_validation , y_val]
)

Comment: ```model.fit(x = [headline_padded_train,art_body_padded_train], y = train_labels_list/train_class_list, epochs = __,..., validation_data = ([headline_padded_validation,art_body_padded_validation],validation_labels))```

Comment: Wait. So is tokenize= Tokenizer(num_words= Max) only being called once? Or am I calling that twice?  Once for head and once for body?

Comment: ```tokenize = Tokenizer()``` is essentially calling/initializing the text vectorizer. Since you are fitting the tokenizer on Headline data and cannot use the same on article body, you need to initialize it again.

Comment: hi @sans_mist i read your answer which is quite accurate, but i have another question in same scenario, what if i have more than one Text columns in the dataframe, how can we tokenize and pad_sequences those columns and reassign them to the Dataframe again. Here is my question posted,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67769093/after-tokenize-a-column-of-text-how-to-reassigned-that-tokenized-output-which